# Ambiguous path separator on Windows - how to handle it?

Tags: java, windows, path, separator

[Another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29623328/why-is-file-pathseparatorchar-a-semicolon-on-windows) brought up an interesting problem:

On Windows, the Java `File.pathSeparatorChar` is `;`, which is correct. However, the semicolon is actually *also* a valid character to folder or file names. You can create a folder named `Test;Test1` on Windows.

The question is: How would you determine whether the semicolon in a path list actually separates a path or is part of the directory name, if the path list can contain both absolute and relative paths?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the path contains a `;` itself the path must be surrounded by double quotes `"`.

following small PoC

```
mkdir "foo;bar"
echo echo execute %%~dpnx0 > "foo;bar\dummy.cmd"
set PATH=%PATH%;"foo;bar"
dummy.cmd
```

the output will be

```
execute R:\temp\foo;bar\dummy.cmd
```

means the `dummy.cmd` is found by the path setup.

**edit** As to see from the comments: Using a semiclon could lead you into some trouble. It's better to avoid using directory names containing a semicolon.

Comment: Ahaa! Now we're talking. This seems reasonable.

Comment: Interesting, this works, but when I tried `which dummy` it didn't find it.

Comment: You mean `where dummy`?

Comment: @stvcisco If you mean the Unix tools `which` it should be `which dummy.cmd`. But it's not found. As `where dummy.cmd` it also didn't find the file I would not blame `which` for that. ;-)

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar Thanks for the `where` command (didn't know that till now). Based on the fact that this is also not able to handle this case. It seems either `;` shouldn't be allowed or the handling of directories this broken some how.

Comment: While this does appear to work, and is (presumably) the correct way to parse such a PATH, I would strongly recommend against adding directory names that contain semicolons to PATH on production systems.

Comment: @HarryJohnston I'm fully agree with you. I add a note to my answer, so nobody can see he was not warned before. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Since the question is for Java, and based on @SubOptimal [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29624187/2698119) that explains that paths with a semicolon should be enclosed in quotes, here's a small code sample to extract paths from such a list separated by `File.pathSeparator`:

```
String separatedList  = "\"test;test1\";c:\\windows;\"test2\";test3;;test4";

String pattern = String.format("(?:(?:\"([^\"]*)\")|([^%1$s]+))%1$s?", File.pathSeparator);
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = p.matcher(separatedList);
while (m.find())
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= m.groupCount(); i++)
    {
        String path = m.group(i);
        if (path != null)
            System.out.println(path);
    }
}
```

For reference, the regex without the escaping characters is `(?:(?:"([^"]*)")|([^;]+));?`.

Answer (score 0):

In a Windows `PATH` the semicolon is always a separator. If you have a folder with a semicolon in the name, you can put its short alternate name in the `PATH`. To find the short name use `DIR /X`.  For example:

```
C:\> dir test* /X
<DIR>   **TEST_T~1**     Test;Test1
C:\> set PATH=TEST_T~1;%PATH%
```

Comment: While I could do that, it really defeats the purpose of allowing long path names in the first place, doesn't it?

Comment: The issue isn't the length of the name, but that it contains the path separator. If you want the `PATH` to interpret your folder as a folder you need to use a form that doesn't contain the separator.