# Java Parent Directory Doesn't Work

Tags: java, file, configuration, io, config

I'm trying to create a file in a specfic folder holding the players data. However, I've ran into two issues.

1. The file doesn't get created.
2. The parent file doesn't get created.

Any ideas would be great, I'm new to the file handling stuff :S

```
public void saveData() {
    // SAVE THE DATA WHEN THE PLAYER QUITS!
   // if (!shouldCreateFile()) return;
    new BukkitRunnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("DEBUG : " + f.getParentFile().exists());
            System.out.println("DEBUG : " + f.getParentFile());
            if (!f.exists()) {
                System.out.println("DEBUG : 2");
                try {
                    System.out.println("DEBUG : 3");
                    if(!f.getParentFile().exists()) f.getParentFile().mkdirs();
                    System.out.println("DEBUG : 4");
                    f.createNewFile();
                    System.out.println("DEBUG : 5");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Bukkit.getServer().getLogger().severe(ChatColor.RED + "******** Could not CREATE the PLAYERDATA file for " + uuid + "! ********");
                }
            }
            d.set("Settings", settings);
            d.set("Kills", kills);
            d.set("Duel_Wins", duelWins);
            d.set("Duel_Losses", duelLosses);
            d.set("Top_KS", topKillstreak);
            try {
                d.save(f);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Bukkit.getServer().getLogger().severe(ChatColor.RED + "******** Could not SAVE the PLAYERDATA file for " + uuid + "! ********");
            }
        }
    }.runTaskAsynchronously(Main.getInstance());
}
```

What outputs into the console:

```
[21:10:36 INFO]: DEBUG : true
[21:10:36 INFO]: DEBUG : plugins/Main:playerdata
```

How f is defined:

```
    f = new File(Main.getInstance().getDataFolder() + File.pathSeparator + "playerdata", uuid.toString() + ".yml");
    d = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(f);
```

Thanks again!

**EDIT :**
It looks like the file **WAS** created, however not in the specified path.
[Here is how it turned out.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Itt8.jpg)

Comment: use `File.separator` instead of `File.pathSeparator`

Comment: have a look at > http://stackoverflow.com/q/5971964/4290096 and  http://stackoverflow.com/q/29623328/4290096

Answer (score 0):

Declare your `File` object like this.

```
f = new File(Main.getInstance().getDataFolder() + File.pathSeparator + "playerdata", uuid.toString() + ".yml");
```

For more reference :

- [File.separator or File.pathSeparator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5971964/4290096)
- [Why is File.pathSeparatorChar a semicolon on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29623328/4290096)
- [Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#pathSeparatorChar)